# How to design a table in a `html` automatically and in a database at the sametime?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, database

I develop a website with different users and organizations(users belong to organizations). There is a database with a user table and an organization table which the website links to.

There is a super admin who can manage the whole website. Here I want to develop a page where the super admin can design table directly on the UI of the website.

For example, he design a table with the components provided by the page. There is "name","score","date". When he clicks "Yes", the table is saved and a table is generated automatically in the database--`create table table1 (name varchar(256),score smallint, mydate date)`. Name is a foreign key of the user table. Then he can create another table to make statistical results of score.

Is there any similar example or any technology or any tools which can achieve the goal?

Answer (score 0):

If you want todo that in Javascript for example, you can try something like : https://github.com/lovasoa/sql.js

You have to write SQL in Javascript.

You can do that with PHP or other language you want.